# Bootstrap 3 - Responsive Visibilities for multiple sizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that uses Bootstrap 3. In that app, I have a toolbar. I only want that toolbar to appear on "md" and "lg" screens. On "xs" and "sm" sized screens, I want a drop-down menu to appear in its place. My question is, how do I do that? Currently, I have the following code, which is available in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QddDE318r8).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
        <li><strong>Joe Smith</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right hidden-xs">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
          <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown hidden-lg">
        <a href="#" data-target="#" class="pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li><button class="btn btn-sup"><i class="fa fa-save"></i><span>Save</span></button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sup"><i class="fa fa-close"></i><span>Close</span></button></li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is, in Bootstrap 3, the [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) do not seem to let define multiple breakpoints for visibility. Is there a way for me to say something like, "if my screen size is "md" or less, show the menu. Otherwise, use the toolbar?" If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: hidden-md and hidden-lg? then it will only visible on -sm and -xs

Comment: Would the dropdown contain the same content as your `md` and `lg` toolbar? If so, Bootstrap has a native navbar that breaks at `sm`, but Bootstrap's CSS can be modified to make it break at `md` instead. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look it up here
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

So on the toolbar you should have

```
<div class="btn-toolbar pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">
```

and on the dropdown

```
<div class="dropdown hidden-md hidden-lg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
    <li><strong>Joe Smith</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3">
  <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right visible-md visible-lg">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
      <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown visible-xs visible-sm">
    <a href="#" data-target="#" class="pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <li><button class="btn btn-sup"><i class="fa fa-save"></i><span>Save</span></button></li>
      <li><button class="btn btn-sup"><i class="fa fa-close"></i><span>Close</span></button></li>
    </ul>        
  </div>
</div>
```